# How to set Spring Session with MongoDB data-store configuration

Tags: spring, mongodb

I was trying to setup a POC of Spring Session with Mongodb as datastore.

Got following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionRepositoryUnavailableException: No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'mongodb')
```

Can anyone help me to identify what did I miss?

application.properties

```
spring.session.store-type=mongodb
server.port=8080

spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=mydb
```

build.gradle

```
>     plugins {
>     id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
>     id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
>     id 'java'    }
> 
> 
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral() }
> 
> dependencyManagement {
>     imports {
>         mavenBom 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-bom:Bean-SR3'
>     } }
> 
> dependencies {
>     compile 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-mongodb'
>     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
>     implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
>     implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
>     testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
> {
>         exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
>     } }
> 
> test {
>     useJUnitPlatform() }
```

Answer (score 1):

This model did not really work for me.
I had to set up the HttpSessionConfig which would bind the mongo container to Spring Session using the annotation **@EnableMongoHttpSession** as advised in [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-session-mongodb)

**@EnableMongoHttpSession seemed to work well for most people**

**Although that did not really work for me** as I have a specific set of properties set on the project which make it Reactive by nature. So I had to switch to **@EnableMongoWebSession**

as such:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.session.data.mongo.JdkMongoSessionConverter;
import org.springframework.session.data.mongo.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableMongoWebSession;

import java.time.Duration;

@Configuration
@EnableMongoWebSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 7200)
public class HttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public JdkMongoSessionConverter jdkMongoSessionConverter() {
        return new JdkMongoSessionConverter(Duration.ofMinutes(120));
    }
}
```

and to be able to use that properly, I had to use these imports in my gradle build, so the proper beans do exist for the WebSession to be able to init.

```
implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-mongodb'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive', version: '2.5.0'
```

The last step for me was to disable the MongoDb store-type from the auto configuration as that was causing issues.
*The following syntax is if you would use application.yml instead of application.properties*

```
session:
    store-type: NONE
```